# Replacement for a sheet pan

Tags: food, kitchen

I have some of those frozen dinners that you cook in the oven (they can be cooked in the microwave but the quality is crap comparatively). The directions say to put the dinner on a sheet pan and place in the oven. Therein lies the problem. I don't have a sheet pan. I don't really have any "oven" pans.

What can I use as a replacement?

Comment: You don't have any flat pieces of metal anywhere near you?

Comment: Unfortunately not. At least not that I would put in my over.

Comment: Even an old rusty sheet of metal will work. Most dinners are cooked at 350 or above which should kill any bacteria.

Answer (score 2):

If you have some aluminum foil, you can double up a few sheets of it to make a substitute "pan" out of the foil. If you wish for it to be a bit sturdier, you can take some sturdy cardboard and wrap it in the foil.

**Note:** be aware that if you are cooking near 400 degrees Fahrenheit or above, the cardboard could catch on fire.

Answer (score 0):

I have used oven safe glass plates (Corningware brand in the US) when I needed a low top pan. You will need to be extremely careful as they can be heavy. When dropped and hot, they can shatter.